# Where does glance store Images from Openstack

Tags: python, linux, cloud, openstack, openstack-horizon

When I `SSH` to glance server there are no images in var/lib/glance/images

```
root@Glance:/var/lib/glance# ls
glance.sqlite  image-cache  images
```

All folders are empty, `glance.sqlite` is 27kb

So where are all Images? My goal is to find them and copy to another Openstack.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not try?

```
glance image-list
glance image-download your_image_id_here > your_image_name.your_image_format
```

example

```
glance image-download 5dde2692-e20c-4c16-a5ff-e9478e14114c > cirros_32bit.qcow2
```

Then you can put them anywhere you want.

make sure you have sourced the credentials or you have to manually pass them as options to the glance command.

```
export OS_USERNAME=your_username
export OS_PASSWORD=your_password
export OS_TENANT_NAME=your_tenant_name
export OS_AUTH_URL=http://your_keystone_ip:35357/v2.0
```

Meanwhile the images are under /var/lib/glance/images/

Comment: Big thanks to you, your short answer helped me to organize my knowledge about openstack. I know everything could be found in documentation, but it is a bit complicated for me so far. You helped me(beginner linux user) a lot.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to find the location of your image, you can find it in DB.
if you are using devstack,

```
#mysql -h localhost -u root -p
mysql> use glance;
mysql> select value from image_locations where image_id="your image ID";
```

You can find the location under value column.